# Unable to tweak the findAssocs() in tm package in R

Tags: r, tm

I was trying to find associations between top 10 frequent words with the rest of the frequent words int the input text.

When I look at the individual output of `findAssocs()`:

```
findAssocs(dtm, "good", corlimit=0.4)
```

It gives the output clearly by printing the word 'good' with which associations have been sought.

```
$good
 better     got    hook    next content     fit  person 
   0.44    0.44    0.44    0.44    0.43    0.43    0.43
```

But when I try to automate this process for a character vector having top 10 words:

`t10 <- c("busi", "entertain", "topic", "interact", "track", "content", "paper", "media", "game", "good")`

the output is a list of correlations for each of those elements BUT WITHOUT THE WORD WITH WHICH THE ASSOCIATIONS HAVE BEEN SOUGHT. The sample output is as below (plz notice that the word at t10[i] is not printed, unlike the above individual output where 'good' was clearly printed):

```
for(i in 1:10) {

   t10_words[i] <- as.list(findAssocs(dtm, t10[i], corlimit=0.4))
}


> t10_words
[[1]]
   littl descript  disrupt    enter    model 
    0.50     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48 

[[2]]
  immers    anyth   effect     full holodeck      iot  problem      say startrek     such  suspect      wow 
    0.68     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48     0.48 

[[3]]
         area        captur          give        overal          like          alon          avid         begin 
         0.51          0.47          0.47          0.47          0.44          0.43          0.43          0.43 
      circuit         cloud collaboration      communic     communiti        concis        confus         defin 
         0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43 
      discord        doesnt          drop enablesupport        esport         event         everi       everyon 
         0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43          0.43
```

How do I print the output along with the actual association word?

Can somebody please help me with this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running your for loop, add the following piece of code:

`names(t10_words) <- t10`

This will name the lists with the words specified in t10.